# Tooltip for dropdown not shown when deployed to Websphere, but is shown when deployed to Tomcat

Tags: jsf-2

Adding dropdown list tag in my xhtml page and using title attribute trying to display the tooltip value.
The tooltip option is working fine when I deploy the application in Tomcat where as the samething is not working in wepsphere application server.

Can anyone please suggest me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat does as being a barebones JSP/Servlet container not ship with any JSF libraries bundled and will use the webapp-supplied JSF libraries. WebSphere does as being a full fledged Java EE container already ship with JSF libraries bundled and will by default ignore the webapp-supplied JSF libraries.

Your concrete problem suggests that WebSphere is using an older JSF version which exposes a bug wherein the tooltip of the dropdown won't be properly rendered. You've basically 2 options:

1. Upgrade WebSphere-bundled JSF version to be the same version as the one which you initially used in Tomcat. Refer WebSphere administration manual for upgrade instructions, or if that isn't your responsibility, tell/ask the server admin to upgrade.
2. Tell WebSphere to use webapp-bundled JSF libraries instead. You can do that in WAS admin console by configuring the "Classloading Policy" of the application to "module" or "PARENT_LAST", depending on WAS version.

Comment: Hi, I have already implemented the second approach (PARENT_LAST) but no hopes.

Comment: What JSF impl/version was you using on Tomcat and which one is been used in WebSphere according its logs?

Comment: Using Mojarra 2.0.6 version

Comment: I asked 2 questions. Which one was you answering and where's the answer on the other question?

Comment: Sorry for that.Using Mojarra 2.1.2 in Tomcat and Mojarra 2.0.6 version in websphere.